# Excel Charts - Do not show Cathegory Name as label, if value is zero

Tags: excel, charts, office365

In Microsoft Excel charts, if the displayed pie label is just value and if you want it not to be shown if it is zero, it can be done through custom formatting

However if I choose to display as label the Value AND the Cathegory Name, the Cathegory Namestays displayed, even if the name is zero.

For example there is a pie that shows sales split on countries. If the sales for USA are zero, and I use custom formatting for the value, the chart displays "Usa,". How to hide the Cathegory Name too?

Thank you